# How to i get a batch file to download a file from a url

Tags: powershell, batch

I've been trying for two days now to try to find something that works. I've been trying to make a batch file download files from a link.

I've tried powershell scripts and invoke-webquest and these crazy four paragraph long download scripts that doesn't work for me.

I would like some help because I'm kind of getting frustrated, but just wondering if anyone has any other suggestions, or if there's a different way to use these scripts..

Comment: It is difficult to help if you don't show the scripts you tried and the error message(s) you get or an explanation in which way it did not work.

Comment: Could you please provide the URLs you are trying to download? Be aware that if you are trying to download, let's say, a picture, you have to use the URL that points to the actual picture, not one of a website that contains the actual picture (because that would download the actual website, that is, an HTML document).

Comment: Using a batchfile is not going to work, but powershell's invoke-webrequest is all you need, just a oneliner to download any file from the internet to your harddisk.

Comment: `powershell.exe -Command (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('%SourcePath%','%TargetPath%')` .. of course you need to fill in source and target with appropriate values.

Comment: Windows 10 build 17063 or later comes with [curl](https://curl.se/) out of the box and can be used to bulk download a text list of URLs in e.g. a batch file.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

We're missing a bit of information in this post to construct a proper answer.

In any case, Powershell is going to help a lot here.

Powershell can do it with just one line of code (or more if you want to go fancy here.

Because I don't know the url of the file you want to download, I'll use Chrome as example, and save the file to the download folder in your user profile.

The url for Chrome is: https://www.google.com/intl/en_us/chrome/

The oneliner script would be:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -uri "https://www.google.com/intl/en_us/chrome" -OutFile "$env:userprofile\Downloads\ChromeSetup.exe"
```

If you want to make it a bit more fancy, you could write the script as follows:

I'll use Notepad++ in this example.

```
$DownloadUrl = "https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/download/v8/npp.8.0.Installer.exe"

$SaveTo = "C:\temp\notepad++_setup.exe"

Invoke-WebRequest -uri $DownloadUrl -OutFile $SaveTo
```

Both scripts are basically the same thing, where one uses just one line with no variables, and the second one stores the parameters into variables such that editing the script lateron is easier, especially if this becomes part of a large script, then you can move the variables to the top of your script so you only need to search there in case you ever need to alter it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so it took me a while but i found this and it worked perfectly fine

```
@echo off
Title Download code from pastebin and display it with batch
Set "url=https://pastebin.com/raw/vzx1dEdW"
for %%# in (%url%) do ( set "File=%tmp%\%%~n#.txt" )
Call :Download "%url%" "%File%"
If exist "%File%" ( 
    ( Type "%File%")>con
Rem to save the contents in new text file
( Type "%File%" > Multi_Downloading_Files.txt)
)
Start "" Multi_Downloading_Files.txt
Pause>nul & Exit
::*********************************************************************************
:Download <url> <File>
Powershell.exe -command "(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('%1','%2')"
exit /b
::*********************************************************************************
```

i got it from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48860214/copy-text-from-url-with-a-batch-file

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 build 17063 or later comes with (slightly older) Windows versions of [curl](https://curl.se/) out of the box e.g.:

```
curl http://example.com/download/file.exe -O
```

`curl` can be called from the command line and or a batch file and doesn't require PowerShell. You can process a text file with a list of URLs via `curl` as follows:

*ex. download_urls.txt*

```
http://example.com/file1.txt
http://example.com/file2.txt
http://example.com/file3.txt
...
```

*ex. curl_download.bat*

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%A IN (download_urls.txt) DO curl %%A -O
```

The official manpage for the latest version of `curl` can be found [here](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html).